# "netsh wlan show networks" only shows the currently connected WiFi network

Tags: windows, command-line, netsh

I am using Windows 10 Pro. Often when I run "netsh wlan show networks" it only shows the currently connected WiFi network. Here is the output from that:

> Interface name : Wi-Fi
>   There are 1 networks currently visible.
>
> SSID 1 : Island Dreams
>      Network type            : Infrastructure
>      Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
>      Encryption              : CCMP

When this happens I have found that if I hover over the WiFi icon in the taskbar I can see all of the available networks. After hovering over the WiFi icon and showing those networks, if I run "netsh wlan show networks" it will now display a list of all of those networks. Here is the output at that point:

> Interface name : Wi-Fi
>   There are 6 networks currently visible.
>
> SSID 1 : Island Dreams
>      Network type            : Infrastructure
>      Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
>      Encryption              : CCMP
>
> SSID 2 : DIRECT-6E-HP OfficeJet Pro 8710
>      Network type            : Infrastructure
>      Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
>      Encryption              : CCMP
>
> ... and so on

If I wait a few minutes and try again netsh will be back to only showing the connected network. And if I hover over the WiFi icon again netsh will once again show all of the networks.

I have verified with a wifi analyzer on my phone that the other networks are always there and have strong signals, even when netsh is only showing the connected network.

Any ideas?

Follow up: I asked three of my co-workers to try the command and it showed all of the available wifi networks for them.

Comment: Try in an elevated cmd: `set autoconfig enabled=yes interface="Wireless Network Connection"`. Replace "Wireless Network Connection" with your own adapter name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. From a cmd prompt as admin I did `netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=yes interface="Wi-Fi"` it responded with `Auto configuration has been enabled on interface "Wi-Fi".` That had no effect on the issue.

Comment: As a follow-up, I tried disabling autoconfig to see what happened. Here is what `netsh wlan show networks` then reported for the "Wi-Fi" interface: `Visible networks cannot be displayed because auto
configuration has been disabled on the interface.` So obviously I want autoconfig enabled and it must have been already enabled before.

Comment: Strange. I would suggest to check for an update to the network adapter driver, or try another USB adapter for Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in some bash snippet (ie. bash.sh).

```
netsh wlan disconnect
sleep 1
netsh wlan show networks
sleep 3
netsh wlan connect ssid="<your_ssid>" name="<your_ssid>"
sleep 120
```

Comment: Does it have to be in bash?

Comment: you can use cmd instead and sleep statements are required for give an interval to OS to scan for visible connections.

Comment: You might want to research the ``timeout`` command (in Windows)  and provide an alternative version of your answer for people who don’t have a Unix or Unix-like subsystem on their Windows platforms.

Comment: yeah possible but the snippet above worked for me in windows command prompt idk if it works for linux, mac or smt else.

Comment: My point (which I guess I never actually said) is that the ``sleep`` command is not standard in all versions of Windows.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll search around. thanks for contribution. :)

Comment: before netsh use powershells “Restart-NetAdapter -Name 'WiFi' -Confirm:$false | Out-Null”